# Recovering deleted/overwritten partition

Tags: grub, partition-recovery, testdisk, parted

**Short**: By mistake I overwrote my partition table using the tool testdisk. I would like to recover my data and operating system. Using the tool `testdisk` I have located the lost partitions on my disk. How can I make them accessible again?

**Short system information**: I have a dual-boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 12.04, each of them on an extra partition. Furthermore, I have my data stored on a third partition. The latter is my particular concern.

**How the problem arose**: After a windows update the system failed to start, thereby showing an NTFS file system error on a blue screen. I tried to resolve the issue by using the built-in windows start problem resolver. It told me that my file system is corrupted and tried to correct the issues. I guess it ran `chkdsk`.

After this was done, the computer restarted, but Windows was missing in the GRUB boot menu. I started my Ubuntu system to restore GRUB. However, it did not detect my Windows OS. Furthermore, I was not able to mount my Windows partition. Somehow, I thought my partition table got corrupted and ran testdisk, which detected the windows partition. Without really knowing what I did, I followed the steps in testdisk and overwrote my partition table (without making a backup before). Yes, I know now that this was not smart.

Afterwards, GRUB was unable to boot anything on my machine. Therefore I booted an Ubuntu live CD. GParted showed my Windows and Linux partitions correctly (but with an error mark). However, my data partition was now shown as unallocated space. Since my data are the most valuable thing on my computer, I have to find a way to restore this partition.

**What I tried so far**: I followed the instruction on this page: [TestDisk Step By Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step). However, the program crashed whenever I wanted to view the files on the detected partitions. Furthermore, I was not sure, whether the found partitions were really the ones that I was looking for.

I found a thread where it was recommended to choose the option `non partitioned media` in `testdisk`. Following this advice I obtained the following promising result:

```
Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

P Linux SWAP 2             0  32 25     0  32 40         16
P FAT12                  165 155 12   165 200 56       2880 [NO NAME]
P Linux SWAP 2           243  27 41   630  36 30    6217712
P ext4                   382 178 51  4971 139 30   73719808
P NTFS                  4971 146 24 31079 146 20  419425017 [Daten]
P NTFS                 23247   0  2 31080   0  1  125837145
P NTFS                 31080   0  1 38912 254 63  125837145 [Windows]
P NTFS                 32386  48 47 38913  70  5  104857600
```

The partition "Daten" is the one I am looking for. Restoring "Windows", too would be great as well. I do not care what happens with my Ubuntu (the ext4 partition).

Again, the program crashed when I tried to view the files (pressing 'p'). Restoring the partition with `testdisk` was not possible, because of the option `non partitioned media`. I therefore tried to restore the files following the raw steps given in the same thread (I cannot give you the link due to my low reputation).

There, the following steps were suggested to be done in `parted`:

> **in parted**:
>
> mktable msdos
>
> unit chs
>
> rescue [C],[H],[S] [C],[H],[S] (use values from the list from testdisk)

However, I did not want to overwrite my partition table again and skipped `mktable msdos`. The procedure did not have any effect.

I searched further and tried to follow the instruction here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121 However, `gpart` did not terminate after 2 hours.

**My question**: How can I make my partition(s) accessible again? I am asking for advice, because I do not want to destroy more by doing things I have low knowledge about.

### Edit

Further information about my disk may be required. The output of `fdsik -l` is

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00001573

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     6146047     3072000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2         6146048   111003647    52428800   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       499300200   625137344    62918572+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

and the out put of `sfdisk -l -uS` is

```
Disk /dev/sda: 38913 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Units = sectors of 512 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot    Start       End   #sectors  Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      2048   6146047    6144000  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2       6146048 111003647  104857600  83  Linux
/dev/sda3     499300200 625137344  125837145   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4             0         -          0   0  Empty
```

Comment: What you need to do IS to recreate a partition table with partition entries that correctly "cover" the filesystems. It does not make much sense to say `However, I did not want to overwrite my partition table again and skipped mktable msdos.` if you already destroyed the original partition table.

Comment: However I am not sure if using `rescue` in `parted` is the best way. It might be a better idea to calculate the LBA and use `fdisk` instead to recreate an appropriate partition table. What's the `CHS` of your DISK?

Comment: Thanks. This is understandable. My concern was just to do it without really knowing what I am doing. `parted` gave me the warning `The existing disk label on /dev/sda will be destroyed and all data on
this disk will be lost.` Will my data really be lost or can I do the steps that I cited without additional concerns? (Of course the data in my partition table will be lost, but the table is garbage anyway...)

Comment: @TomYan: Can you give me some guidance on how to `calculate the LBA and use fdisk`? (Or maybe a link to a page that helps...) How can I find out what the `CHS` of my disk is? I added the output of `fdisk -l` to my post. Is this, what you asked for?

Comment: Never mind. Can you manage to recreate the partition table with `fdisk` as [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/knOss.png) shows? Or you can `dd` [this](https://ptpb.pw/GaQ1.bin) to your drive instead (It's the dump of the MBR / partition table I created as shown in the screenshot).

Comment: @TomYan: I added the output of `sfdisk -l` to my post, which looks kind of what you were asking for. It does not include the size in GB, but I guess this is not important for you. If it is still of importance: Can you tell me how I can `dd` something into my drive?

Comment: For example, `dd if=GaQ1.bin of=/dev/sda count=1`; make sure `sda` is the drive you want to write (e.g. with `fdisk -l`) right before you run the command, since it may not persistently be `sda` among boots; `count=1` is optional, just in case you use the wrong source (`if=`) somehow; with `count=1` it will prevent dd from destroying the filesystems/data apart from the MBR / partition table.

Comment: Thanks @TomYan! Ok, I did that. Now, `fdisk -l` gives the following output: `Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System;
/dev/sda1         6148094    79868335    36860121   83  Linux;
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2        79868336   499300199   209715932    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT;
/dev/sda3       499300200   625142447    62921124    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT` However, I failed to mount any of the partitions. I get the answer that the partitions do not have valid NTFS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38484/discussion-between-samufi-and-tom-yan).